# Performance profiler for .NET with an API

Tags: .net, profiling

I'd like a profiling application for .NET with an API for me to use to gain on-the-fly metrics and then dynamically alter application settings for performance optimisation.

Does such a program exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) from JetBrains. One great benefit is the integration capabilities with Visual Studio.

[Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/documentation/high-profile_profiling.html) is a good introduction.

Answer (score 3):

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) from JetBrains is good and has nice API

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [**ANTS Performance Profiler**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) and **[ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

One more to add to the pot: [JustTrace](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx&ei=ta0eUa_3F4rPqgHd84GADQ&usg=AFQjCNFinPnNAvmWp4_aAryxxINu4j5V8A) from Telerik.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Telerik MVP -- not an employee, but a big fan).

> JustTrace enables real-time monitoring of an application during
>   execution. When an abnormality is observed, simply take a snapshot and
>   investigate the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Tons of info on SO. [Search for it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+profiler).